# Convert a CVD image to a Color OpenCV image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, augmented-reality

I am working with an existing codebase that creates [CVD images](http://www.edwardrosten.com/cvd/cvd/html/tutorial1.html) from a webcam before doing processing. My aim is to run marker detection on this image for augmented reality before the rest of the processing happens and I am planning to do this using [ArUco](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26). The problem is that ArUco takes in a OpenCV image in order to detect the markers.

I am thinking of manually creating this OpenCV image from the CVD image by manually accessing each pixel of the CVD image and sticking the RGB values into a new OpenCV image. I am not too familiar with working with C++ but surely there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use something like this.  The type for myImage is a (custom) image type that stores the 3 bytes for each pixel of the image in consecutive bytes of memory, and myImage.data() is a pointer to the start of that memory.  If your CVD image (which I'm not familiar with) is laid out in a similar way, you can do the same.

```
cv::Mat image(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, myImage.data());
```

Comment: Yes, you definitely want to wrap the image without doing a copy if at all possible.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I want to do. According to the CVD image documentation, I can dereference the value of each pixel by using the [] operator but I can't seem to find how to get the starting block of memory for the image. From your code above I am guessing rows = width of image, cols= height and CV_8UC3 is the image format? Is there documentation for the function above so I can try and figure out what image format is applicable?

Comment: look at opencv.itseez.com for docs, and find the address of the first element with &image[0,0]. CV_8UC3 stands for unsigned, 8 bit (uchar is the standard image type), 3 channels (RGB).